Galois group for $\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$
Edit: My original example is too special... I want to consider galois group of $\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ where minipoly of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ is different from over $\Bbb Q$.
Edit: I fixed a serious typo.
Edit: I know that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8,\sqrt 2)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$, but this does no help for me to understand this method, maybe I can comeup with a more general example so that the field can't be simplified? like $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}},i)/\Bbb Q)$?
I want to compute Galois group for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\zeta_8)$. I know the answer is $K_4=\Bbb Z_2^2$, but I don't understand the process:
My TA gave me the following steps:

conjugate elements of $\sqrt2$ are $\pm\sqrt2$, of $\zeta_8$ are $\zeta_8^k,k=1,3,5,7$

we wish to send each generator to one of its conjugate, for simpler problems like $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt3, \sqrt 5)$ we are already done (just consider sending then independently) but here it's more complicated since once we fix a conjugate of $\sqrt2$, it will influence our choice of conjugate of $\zeta_8$.

Let's cosider minimal poly of $\zeta_8$ over $\Bbb Q$: $x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)$, its minimal poly over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is one of the factor, say $x^2-\sqrt2x+1$.

If $\sigma:\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt2$, then $\sigma$ wont change minipoly of $\zeta_8$ so we send $\zeta_8\mapsto\zeta_8\text{ or }\zeta_8^7$. If $\sigma:\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$, then $\sigma$ does change minipoly of $\zeta_8$ to $x^2+\sqrt2x+1$ so we send $\zeta_8\mapsto\zeta_8^3\text{ or }\zeta_8^5$. Now we have found all elements in galois group.


I basically get the intuition and fully understand step 1 to 3, but I don't understand step 4 and how to describe this whole process strictly in mathematical language. For example:

Why is the minipoly 'changed' by $\sigma$? I doubt this is wrong because minipoly cannot be changed, but how do we describe this intuitive step? I tried this: if $\sigma:\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt2$ then $\sigma$ is actually a $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$-automorphism, in this case $\zeta_8$ has to be mapped to its conjugate element in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ i.e. $\zeta,\zeta_8^7$. But this argument fail when $\sigma:\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$.
Is the above steps a general method to compute galois groups? I'd like to apply this to compute galois group of $x^4+x^2-1$ over $\Bbb Q$. i.e. $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}},i)/\Bbb Q)$


If the penny didn't drop, compute $(\zeta_8+\zeta_8^{-1})^2$.

A priori there is no way to know which factor of $x^4+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ has $\zeta_8$ as a root. You can surely figure that out. Also, using the result of the previous comment expand the product
$$(x-\zeta_8)(x-\zeta_8^7)$$ to answer the questions 3 and 4.

I don't understand why you say that the answer is $D_4$. We have $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{8}) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$, and we know the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)\mid \Bbb Q)$, which is $U(n)$, the group of units of the ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. For a reference see for example here:
Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}))\cong \mathbb{Z_n}^*$
For $n=8$, $\phi(8)=4$, and the Galois group is $U(8)\cong C_2\times C_2$. In particular, the Galois group is abelian.
So your proof really should focus on the cyclotomic extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)\mid \Bbb Q$.

This is not correct. $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$ already contains $\sqrt{2}$

@LukasHeger Sorry, typo corrected. I added an reference for the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is contained in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$.

I'm sorry, I meant to write $K_4$, the klein 4-group. that was a typo

$\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$ and thus $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\zeta_8) = \Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$, which has Galois group $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times =(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Sorry, I made a typo, the galois group is $K_4=\Bbb Z_2^2$

Moreover, I understand your argument, but I think I need some help understanding the mentioned method. Maybe there are some cases where the field is not degenerate to such a simple case :)

@Westlifer We know that $\sqrt{2}\in \Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ if and only if $n$ is divisible by $8$. Then it is simple to solve.

@Dietrich Burde yes, that was clear to me, but I think that was not what I need, I want to understand the mentioned method cause I believe it will help me solve a more general class of problems. see my edit on the question. Thank you!

@Westlifer I think, that the other result, namely for $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)\mid \Bbb Q$ is much more useful in your case, and it works for all $n$, so it generalises nicely. The other cases are more difficult in general, and there is no unique method for all of them.

@Dietrich Burde yes, I can prove this result. So would you look at the other question? I think that galois group better described my question. My original example is too special... I want to consider $\Bbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ where minipoly of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ is different from over $\Bbb Q$
